# Determine Source of XAML Styling

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app

I have a couple of `ListView`s on different pages in my UWP application. For some reason, one of them seems to have `Padding` along the bottom below the last `ListViewItem`, while the other does not.

Neither of them has bottom `Padding` specified, so I'm wondering if this could be inherited from a parent control? I searched the entire XAML of the one with `Padding`, and it is not set anywhere else either. It isn't a huge problem, but I would prefer my controls to be consistent throughout my application, and I think adding the bottom `Padding` to the `ListView` without it to make them match seems silly, especially when I am unsure of why the first one has `Padding` in the first place.

Is there somewhere to determine where properties are set in the hierarchy, similar to the way CSS works?

Here is what they look like:

No padding: [image: no padding]

Padding: [image: padding]

I added a `Background` to the `ListView` control to verify that there is no `Padding` there..

[image: background]

So it would seem it would have to come from the `ListViewItem` itself, but it does not have the `Padding` property set.

Comment: You could grab XAMLSpy or an equivalent. One's like those are generally found pretty quick though just looking for style overrides set at a specific targettype like ListBoxItem or TextBlock or something. Would probably have to see it to tell.

Comment: If the list box is sized to its container, and the interior size of the listbox is not an integer multiple of the height of one of its items, there will have to be space after the last item. Win32 listboxes did integral sizing, but a quick google suggests that XAML doesn't have that concept.

Comment: P.S. The padding area will have the background color of the element control; the margin area will not. So the purpose just indicates that it's not the item's padding (which in principle is possible -- maybe the green inside the item is some inner thing with a transparent parent).

Comment: I will give XAMLSpy a try. I tried commenting out all of the `Style` resources, regardless of the `TargetType`, and still having same issue. Definitely seems to be narrowed down to just the `ListViewItem` styling, but not sure what yet.

Comment: It's usually just some dumb little nuance detail you don't catch until you walk away for a minute and come back to find it right in front of you the whole time. The joys of dev.

Comment: Well, it looks like I can narrow it down to the `ListViewItem` as previously suspected, but XAML Spy gives me an error on the right hand side, so it isn't very helpful except drawing a dotted line around different elements. I've tried reinstalling, but just keep getting "Failed to load object members (Unable to cast object of type 'System.__ComObject' to type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.IRichEditBoxStatics4'.)

Comment: The `ItemsStackPanel` takes up the full space, but the next child, `ListViewItem` does not. So either the `ItemsStackPanel` has a `Padding` set, or the `ListViewItem` has a `Margin` or something, but that can't be, since multiple `ListViewItems` can be displayed with no gaps in between.

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be that one of the parent controls of the `ListView` that was displaying correctly (how I wanted it to) had a `VerticalAlignment="Top"` set, while all the parents of the other `ListView` were set to `VerticalAlignment="Stretch"`.

I was finally able to get XAML Spy working properly, and it was helpful in previewing the changes while the application was running so that I could determine which element I needed to set the `VerticalAlignment` on without recompiling over and over again. Thanks to @ChrisW for the recommendation.